# Working with styling with Typescript and ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, button, styling

I am new to this and would like some examples with styling controls such as button using Typescript and ReactJs

Any help appreciated

Comment: CSS works the same in Typescript as it does in Javascript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of options. Here are few:

## CSS Classnames

Load a css file e.g.

```
.red {
  color : red;
}
```

And then use `className` prop : https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname e.g.

```
<div className="red">I am red </div>
```

## Style

Use the style attribute:

```
<div style={{color: 'red'}}>I am red </div>
```

## Use a css in js lib

There are a lot of options. I wrote typestyle specifically for excellent typescript support : https://typestyle.github.io/

Comment: Thank you really helpful